# How to store table column names into array using access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am pretty new to VBA . I have a table contains more than 30 fields. How do i store the column names into array using vba

My vba Code

```
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim fld As Field
Dim o As Integer

Set tdf = db.TableDefs(tablename)
Dim n As Integer
n = tdf.Fields.Count
ReDim tablecolumns(0 To n) As String

For o = 0 To n
    tablecolumns(n) = fld.Name(o)
Next o
```

Giving an error in this line

```
  tablecolumns(n) = fld.Name(o)
```

Comment: edit: whoops. Brain melt - thought this was Excel. Comment removed.

Comment: There a number of ways to do this. For example you could [query the Msysobjects table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4895805/119477) and then loop over the recordset if you're talking about an Access table.

Comment: @simoco I've added the code. please have a look

Comment: `tablecolumns(n) = fld.Name(o)`-->`tablecolumns(o) = tdf.Fields(o).Name` and `For o = 0 To n`--> `For o = 0 To n-1`

Comment: Darn it @simoco, post some of these as answers so the questions can be closed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I'm modifying my answer to match your code.

```
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim fld As Field
Dim o As Integer

Set tdf = db.TableDefs(tablename)
Dim n As Integer
n = tdf.Fields.Count
Dim tablecolumns() As String
ReDim tablecolumns(0 To n-1)

For o = 0 To n-1
    tablecolumns(o) = tdf.Fields(o).Name
Next o
```